# Why Ternary operator needs to be put in parenthesis?

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1 = "one";
        String str2 = "two";
        String str3 = "three";
        String str4 = "four";
        String str5 = null;
        String str6 = "six";
        String str7 = "seven";
        char seperator = ',';
        String str = str1 + seperator + str2 + seperator + str3 + seperator + str4
                + seperator + (str5==null?"":str5) + seperator + str6 + seperator + str7;
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```

The result:

```
one,two,three,four,,six,seven
```

If I remove the parentheses around the ternary operator, then the result is this:

```
null,six,seven
```

Would you please explain this behavior?

Comment: It's called [Operator Precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Comment: it is concatenating str5 with the first part first and then checking if it is equal to `null`

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the parentheses then it will add all the strings together and check for null like this:

```
String str = ((str1 + seperator + str2 + seperator + str3 + seperator + str4
            + seperator + str5)==null?"":str5) + seperator + str6 + seperator
```

It adds `str1 + seperator + str2 + .... + str5` all together and then checks if they are equal to `null`, which they are not, so it prints `str5`, which is `null` then it prints the rest